# QML sequential animations avoid code duplication

Tags: animation, qml, bezier, qt3d

I have a little animation going on using Qt3D in QML.
The point of the animation is to have a ball going from a point p0 to a point p2 following a Bezier curve given a point p1 that I compute somehow (nothing to do with the question) so that I get a quadrtic bezier curve.
Since there is no such thing as BezierAnimation, what I do is I have a Vector3DAnimation form p0 to the point at 0.1 of the curve, then from 0.1 to 02, and so on until 0.9 to 1 (which is p2).

This gives me this horrible looking code:

```
SequentialAnimation{
    loops: Animation.Infinite
    Vector3DAnimation{
        from: bezierAt(0)
        to: bezierAt(0.1)
        duration: durationFromSpeed(0,0.1,500)
    }
    Vector3DAnimation{
        from: bezierAt(0.1)
        to: bezierAt(0.2)
        duration: durationFromSpeed(0.1,0.2,500)
    }
    Vector3DAnimation{
        from: bezierAt(0.2)
        to: bezierAt(0.3)
        duration: durationFromSpeed(0.2,0.3,500)
    }
    ....
    Vector3DAnimation{
        from: bezierAt(0.9)
        to: bezierAt(1)
        duration: durationFromSpeed(0.9,1,500)
    }
}
```

As you can see the codes is tremendously simple since I encapsulated most of it in functions, but it is too repetitie and has very bad scalability (if I wanted to have a step of 0.01 I would ahve to write by hand 100 animations).

So, my question is, is there any way to make that nicer?

I tried using a ScriptAction, like this:

```
SequentialAnimation{
    id: anim
    loops: Animation.Infinite
    property real current:0.0
    function incr() {
        current+=0.1
        current = current > 1? 0.0 : current
    }
    Vector3DAnimation{
       from: bezierAt(anim.current)
       to: bezierAt(anim.current+0.1)
       duration: durationFromSpeed(anim.current,anim.current+0.1,500)
    }
    ScriptAction: {script: incr();}
}
```

But this, strangely only does the first part of the animation (even though I checked and current changes correctly), and after 4 or 5 iterations suddenly stops working.

Is there a good looking way to do this? I really want to be able to modify the step...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work.

Simply added anim.restart() at the end of the incr() function and it works perfectly now.